# Render json data into Angular2

Tags: json, http, angular

I want to render some data from **.json** into component view in my Angular2 project, but instantly getting errors.

**releases.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ReleasesService {

    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    fetchData(){
        return this.http.get('app/releases.json').map(
            (res) => res.json());
    }
}
```

**releases-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReleasesService } from './releases.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'releases-list',
    templateUrl: 'releases-list.component.html',
    providers: [ReleasesService]

})

export class ReleasesListComponent implements OnInit { 

    constructor (private releasesService: ReleasesService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.releasesService.fetchData().subscribe(
            (data) => console.log(data)
        );
    }
}
```

**releases.component.html**

```
<div class="releases-list-component">

    <div>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let release of releases">{{releases.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
```

In my **releases.service.ts** file I tried changing

```
('app/releases.json')
```

to

```
('./releases.json')
```

or

```
('releases.json')
```

or

```
('/releases.json')
```

but nix helped.

Console errors:
[image]

Folder tree:

```
-Project folder:
--app //app root
--releases //folder with service and component, etc
--releases.json //file in the app root
- index.html
```

Comment: What is your folder structure like?

Comment: @echonax Updated my question. Both service / component folder and separate json file are in the root of my app.

Comment: Where is your index.html?

Comment: Updated again, index.html is in the project folder - outside the app folder

Comment: Check this: https://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info it should be working

Comment: No more console errors - thank you! But Observable<Response> line gets underlined (Cannot find name 'Response'). Don't you know how to fix it?
And the data is still not rendered in the view.

Comment: I don't know where you use the observable but you can just use `Observable<any>`

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Comment: Still trying... No errors, but nothing's rendered as well